# Gathering the contents of several rows in R based on a key value

Tags: r

I have a data set with observations over time and there is more than 1 observation per date. 
I want to gather in a single row the observations of a same day but I am not sure how, is there a function that does that in R?

Comment: You probably want to look at `spread` in the `tidyr` package. But consider whether you *really* want to make your data "wide", instead of "long". Long data (1 row per observation) is often easier to analyse in R. Also, please provide some example data and example desired output.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example in order for us to test possible solutions and to understand exactly what you mean in your question.

Comment: have a look at those links here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   and the following should help with your particular question: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)